# MySQL Foreign Key constraint error - Failed to add foreign key constraint - error 1822

Tags: mysql

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have two tables, `Employee` and `EventPlan`.

For the create table of the `EventPlan` table, when I try to create the table, I get an error in MySQL workbench:

> Error 1822 - Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index
> for constraint "EmpNo" in the referenced table "employee".

You will see in both tables `EmpNo` is included. But I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Please see code below.

I cannot execute or create the `EventPlan` table in My SQL workbench.

I have reviewed both tables, also made the columns unique, but cannot find the issue.

`EventPlan` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Eventplan
( 
    PlanNo VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    EventNo VARCHAR(8) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Workdate DATE,
    Notes VARCHAR(8),
    EmpNo VARCHAR(8),

    CONSTRAINT PK_PlanNo PRIMARY KEY(PlanNo),
    CONSTRAINT EventNo FOREIGN KEY (EventNo) 
         REFERENCES Eventrequest(EventNo),
    CONSTRAINT EmpNo FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo)
         REFERENCES Employee(EmpNo)
);
```

`Employee` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    EmpNo VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    EmpName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Department VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PKEmployee PRIMARY KEY(EmpNo)
);
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically fine if you define employee first , and comment out the fk to eventrequest. - You should include eventrequest definition in the question. It doesn't make a lot of sense to have empno with different lengths and defining  as unique in employee is a bit pointless since empno is a primary key.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you for your feedback. Could you clarify what you mean by - "and comment out the fk to eventrequest. - You should include eventrequest definition in the question."

Comment: You have a FK on eventrequest but have not included eventrequest table definition so I had to comment out this fk to get the published code to syntax. It would be vexing if we solved your immediate problem only for another to come alone related to eventrequest. A rule for fks is that the referenced tables have to be created before the referencing tables.

Comment: Thanks P.Salom, that makes sense. I have updated the tables as mentioned, but still not working. I excluded the eventrequest FK as you mentioned, but still getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine

```
MariaDB [test]> drop table if exists employee;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE Employee
    -> (EmpNo VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    -> EmpName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    -> Department VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    -> Email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    -> Phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    -> CONSTRAINT PKEmployee PRIMARY KEY(EmpNo)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE Eventplan
    -> ( PlanNo VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    -> EventNo VARCHAR(8) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    -> Workdate DATE,
    -> Notes VARCHAR(8),
    -> EmpNo VARCHAR(8) ,
    -> CONSTRAINT PK_PlanNo PRIMARY KEY(PlanNo),
    -> #CONSTRAINT EventNo FOREIGN KEY (EventNo)
    -> #REFERENCES Eventrequest(EventNo),
    -> CONSTRAINT EmpNo FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo)
    -> REFERENCES Employee(EmpNo)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name in('employee','eventplan') and table_schema = 'test';
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| employee   |
| eventplan  |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

If you are still having errors then it's not from here.